# Redirect to DataObject edit page inside BetterButton custom action

Tags: php, silverstripe

I'm trying to create a custom button that clones a `DataObject` using the [unclecheese/betterbuttons v.1.2](https://github.com/unclecheese/silverstripe-gridfield-betterbuttons) module.

Everything is working fine but at the end I would like to redirect the user to the newly created DataObject edit page instead of refresh/go back. How can I do this?

Here is my custom button code:

```
class GridFieldCloneBetterButton extends DataExtension {

    private static $better_buttons_actions = array(
        'clone_do'
    );

    public function updateBetterButtonsActions($actions) {
        $actions->push(
            BetterButtonCustomAction::create('clone_do', 'Clone')
                ->setSuccessMessage('Object cloned')
                ->setRedirectType(BetterButtonCustomAction::GOBACK)
        );
        return $actions;
    }

    public function clone_do() {
        $current_record = $this->owner;
        $clone = $this->owner->duplicate();
    }

}
```

Maybe if I can access `GridFieldDetailForm_ItemRequest` from inside the `DataExtension` I can make this work, but I really don't know how to do it.

Comment: This isn't supported at the moment. Could you put this in as a ticket on the Github page, and we can follow up there?

Comment: Off course I can, thanks a lot! Here the issue: https://github.com/unclecheese/silverstripe-gridfield-betterbuttons/issues/70